# Convergence of average of sums

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of real numbers, and define $s_n=a_1+\ldots+a_n$ for all $n$. Define $t_n=\dfrac{s_1+s_2+\ldots+s_n}{n}$. There is a theorem that if $\{s_n\}$ converges, then $\{t_n\}$ converges (to the same limit, I believe).

Does the converse hold? That is, if $\{t_n\}$ converges, then does $\{s_n\}$ converge?

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with $a_n$. You can start the question at: "Define $t_n=$... And the answer is no. See [Cesaro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) which has the same counterexample as T.Bongers'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Choose $s_n = (-1)^n$; then

$$t_k = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} -\frac{1}{n} &: n \text{ odd} \\ 0 &: n \text{ even} \end{array}\right.$$